# How to pass the php result to google maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using this php code to retrieve lat and lon from MySQL database,the result values should be given as input to the google map.so when i run the query the output should go to google maps. as parameters how can i do this?

This is the php code.

```
    mysql_select_db("theatdb", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Lat,Lon FROM theaters
    WHERE theater_name='theater_name'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['theater_name'];
      echo "<br />";
      }
    ?>
```

This is the google maps code

```
 function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.91869,77.594051);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```

The php code is retrieving the lat and lon value i want to pass the result to google maps.how can i do that? anyone help m..  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get associative array from your database since you are getting only one result:

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db("theatdb", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Lat,Lon FROM theaters WHERE theater_name='theater_name'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['theater_name'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['Lat'];?>,<?php echo $row['Lon'];?>);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated.

Comment: Tell him not me, I corrected his code. Is his option to move to PDO or not

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this what ur trying to get or ur refering to something else

```
var lat  = <?php echo $result['lat'] ?>; 
var lang  = <?php echo $result['lang'] ?>;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);
```